# Elisp find changed regions of buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer

I'm writing an Emacs plugin and ran into a challenge. I have a command that formats a region to my specifications. It's perl, and it does somethings I don't want it to try to do while I'm editing, like this:

```
my $foo = "foo";
my $fooer = "fooer";
```

becomes

```
my $foo   = "foo";
my $fooer = "fooer";
```

However, I am working in a code repository full of code that I have not written that I do not want to change.

I have written a command that operates on a region and performs exactly as expected, but I want to add a hook to before-save to format blocks there. Is there a way to get regions of changes, but ignore unchanged regions?

I've considered using highlight-changes functionality, but had a hard time finding anything usefull. I've also thought about trying to use the git blame, but that seems like it would take a lot of time to do something simple.

Is there Elisp functionality to get only modified regions of a buffer? I know `ws-butler` only formats modified lines, and the [Emacs wiki](http://leverages%20highlight-changes-mode%20to%20track%20modified%20lines.) claims it 'Leverages `highlight-changes-mode` to track modified lines.', but I read the source for `ws-butler` and was just confused by a total lack of any mention of `highlight-changes-mode`.

Comment: It looks like `ws-butler` copies code from `highlight-changes-mode` rather than depending on it directly.  [`ws-butler-map-changes`](https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler/blob/52321b99be69aa1b661da7743c4421a30d8b6bcb/ws-butler.el#L210) is the one you want to reference.  At a glance, the way it works is by assigning a special text property on change, then detecting that property later.

Comment: Thank you @0x5453, this answers the question. I will write up an answer for others who come to this post when I can.

Comment: FYI the Wiki is just outdated there.  As I recall, the original `ws-butler` implementation did use `highlight-changes-mode` directly, and a subsequent reimplementation or refactoring separated it.